# SQL query out multiple join table data

Tags: sql

Currently have 5 different table name with all have relation. And i am confuse on how to query into row.

Product
productDescription
Category
categoryDescription
categoryToProduct

```
Product table
productID    productQuantity      productPrice
1                 50                    100
2                 50                    40
3                 50                    300
4                 30                    20

productDescription
productID    productName      productImageLink
1                 asus          x
2                 razer         x
3                 apple         x
4                 gigabyte      x

Category
categoryID
1
2
3
4

categoryDescription
categoryID categoryName 
1              pc
2             laptop
3             mobile
4           accessories

categoryToProduct
categoryID             productID
2                          1
2                          2
3                          3
2                          4
```

What i tried :

```
"SELECT ctp.productID as product_id , ctp.categoryID as category_id, pd.productName as product_name FROM categoryToProduct ctp LEFT JOIN product p ON (ctp.productID = p.productID) LEFT JOIN productDescription pd ON (p.productID = pd.productID) LEFT JOIN category c ON(ctp.categoryID = c.categoryID) WHERE ctp.categoryID = 2";
```

What i wanted :

> Display all product description (name,image,price) and loop into row
>   where "category" of the product is 2

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @mkRabbani Display productName , productImageLink,productPrice based on the CategoryID "2"

Comment: Is PHP related to your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this following query-

```
SELECT B.ProductName,
B.productImageLink,
D.productPrice
FROM categoryToProduct A
INNER JOIN productDescription B ON A.ProductId = B.ProductId
INNER JOIN Product D ON B.ProductId = D.ProductId 
WHERE A.categoryID = 2
```

Note: Not sure why you have so many tables where you may merge category and categoryDescription tables into 1 table and also Product and productDescription tables.

Comment: i just taking over the project that was given by my other teammate , going to overhaul whole db , but now just trying to fix the problem .

Thanks , will update when try it

Comment: it works for me , but there is a bug which is example : Have 3 rows for categoryID "2" , but when i query out using your code , it show 6

Comment: But it should return 3 rows. You can check the demo for MSSQL here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb8eea081ac5a39d065e7add79b71d5d